# Dynamicly required field in django form?

Tags: django

I want to make select field in my html form, which has available selectable options and "Add new" option in the list. By selecting "Add new" I want to fade in required text input control. If any of available options is selected, form doesn't react as text input required or not filled in. 
Is it possible to make this with django forms only or do I need to use reqular form field `required=False` setting and handle form validation in the front end?

Answer (score 0):

you can access to your widget attributes overriding the init() method:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if condition:
            self.fields['my_field'].required = True
            self.fields['my_field'].widget.attrs['required'] = 'required'
```